# Wix service not listed in the local services

Tags: wix, windows-services, windows-installer, wix3.8, procrun

I used procrun to create a windows service and tried to install it using WIX. I have placed all the required registry keys at the relevant places. But the service is still not listed in the local services. Below is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

  <Product Id="*" Name="DummyInstaller" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Bryan" UpgradeCode="94D1BC64-7CC1-45DA-BD5F-8ED40980E75C">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Platform="x64"/>

    <Property Id="JAVA_CURRENT_VERSION64">
      <RegistrySearch Id="JRE_CURRENT_VERSION_REGSEARCH64" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" Name="CurrentVersion" Type="raw" Win64="yes" />
    </Property>

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="DummyInstaller" Level="1" >
      <!--<ComponentGroupRef Id="NewFilesGroup" />-->
      <ComponentRef Id="REGISTRY_A" />
      <ComponentRef Id="PROCRUN.EXE"/>
    </Feature>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFiles">
        <Directory Id="DummyDir" Name="DummyInstaller">
          <!--<Directory Id="MyProgramDir" Name="MosquittoNew" />-->
          <Directory Id="SERVERDIR" Name="Kube2UpdaterService">
            <Component Id="REGISTRY_A" DiskId="1" Guid="*" Win64="no">
              <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Kube2UpdaterService\Parameters\Java" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Classpath" Value="E:\Service\Update_Service-1.0.jar" KeyPath="yes" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Jvm"     Value="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll" />
                <RegistryValue Type="multiString" Action="append" Name="Options">
                  <MultiStringValue Type="multiString" Name="Options" Action="append">-Duser.language=en</MultiStringValue>
                  <MultiStringValue Type="multiString" Name="Options" Action="append">-Duser.region=US</MultiStringValue>
                </RegistryValue>
                <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="JvmMs" Value="256" />
                <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="JvmMx" Value="1024" />
                <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="JvmSs" Value="4000" />
              </RegistryKey>
              <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Kube2UpdaterService\Parameters\Log" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Path" Value="c:\logs" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Level" Value="Error" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Prefix" Value="Kube2UpdaterService" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="StdError" Value="c:\logs\stderr.txt" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="StdOutput" Value="c:\logs\stdout.txt" />
              </RegistryKey>
              <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Kube2UpdaterService\Parameters\Start" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Mode" Value="jvm" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Class" Value="com.kohls.kube.services.updater.UpdaterServiceMain" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Params" Value="start" />
              </RegistryKey>
              <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Kube2UpdaterService\Parameters\Stop" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Mode" Value="jvm" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Class" Value="com.kohls.kube.services.updater.UpdaterServiceMain" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Method" Value="stop" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Params" Value="stop" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="StdOutput" Value="auto" />
              </RegistryKey>
              <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Kube2UpdaterService" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Description" Value="Kube updater service performing updates and installation" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="DisplayName" Value="Kube2UpdaterService" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="ImagePath" Value="E:\Service\prunsrv.exe //RS//Kube2UpdaterService" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="DependsOnService" Value="Tcpip Afd" />
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="ObjectName" Value="LocalSystem" />
                <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="ErrorControl" Value="1" />
                <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="Start" Value="2" />
                <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="Type" Value="16" />
              </RegistryKey>
              <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Kube2UpdaterService\Parameters" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Test" Value="Pass" />
              </RegistryKey>
            </Component>

            <Component Id="PROCRUN.EXE" DiskId="1" Guid="468C2DB3-F722-4DE6-8A91-B6FB8009757D" Win64="no">
              <!-- this is the renamed procrun 64 bit executable -->
              <File Id="prunsrv.exe" Name="prunsrv.exe" Source="E:\Service\prunsrv.exe" />
              <ServiceInstall Id="PROCRUN" Type="ownProcess" Name="Kube2UpdaterService" DisplayName="Kube2UpdaterService" Description="Kube 2.0 Updater Service" Start="auto" Account="LocalService"  ErrorControl="normal" Arguments=" //RS//Kube2UpdaterService" />
              <ServiceControl Id="StartPRUNSRV" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="Kube2UpdaterService" Wait="no" />
            </Component>
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

</Wix>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All registry keys under HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services are considered internal to Windows.  The supported way in MSI to configure Windows Services is to use the Service* tables, like [`ServiceInstall`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/serviceinstall.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your:

```
<File Id="prunsrv.exe" Name="prunsrv.exe" Source="E:\Service\prunsrv.exe" />
```

needs to set be

```
<File Id="prunsrv.exe" Name="prunsrv.exe" Source="E:\Service\prunsrv.exe" Keypath="yes" />
```

I don't know why, but it helps